# Why is the scope parameter required in spring-security-oauth oauth 2.0 implemenetation

Tags: java, security, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing an OAuth 2.0 provider for my company's REST API using `spring security oauth`.
For some reason when using the Token endpoint `spring security oauth` mandates the client to send their desired scope as a request parameter (this happens in the `ClientCredentialsChecker.validateScope` method).
As I understand the spec section about [Access Token Scope](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25#section-3.3) the scope parameter is optional BUT a provider can decide it fails an authorization request if no scope exists.
My questions are:

- Do I understand correctly the spec as allowing a provider to mandate
  the scope?
- Does anyone know why `spring security oauth` chose to implement the stricter interpretation of the spec without allowing this to be configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question here really comes down to the concept of scope binding.  You're right that the specification states that the scope parameter is optional, but whether the scope has to be defined in a service implementing OAuth 2 is really up to the implementer (in this case Spring).

Now to the concept of scope binding.  When implementing scopes, or the information that you want to be able to access from a user, you have two basic types - bound and unbound scopes.  When using bound scopes, the scopes will need to be defined when you create your application and get your OAuth key and secret.  If implementing unbound scopes (like Spring), the scopes need to be defined during the first redirect call to have the user auth.  In many cases when no scopes are defined, a service implementing unbound scopes will use a default set of user details that you can access.  It appears that in the Spring case the scope is required.

Disclaimer: I have not worked with the Spring security OAuth implementation before.

Just to give you some visuals on the difference between bound and unbound, here are some examples:

Facebook uses unbound scopes to request user data, so their initial redirect request can look like this:

```
//construct Facebook auth URI
$auth_url = sprintf("%s?redirect_uri=%s&client_id=%s&scope=email,publish_stream", 
            $authorization_endpoint, 
            $callback_url, 
            $key);
```

In the case of Gowalla (back when Gowalla was still available), they used scopes that were bound to the OAuth key, so when you made that initial request the scope didn't need to be defined, giving you a request that looked more like this (notice the missing scope param):

```
//construct Gowalla auth URI
$auth_url = sprintf("%s?redirect_uri=%s&client_id=%s", 
            $authorization_endpoint, 
            $callback_url, 
            $key);
```

I hope that helps,

Jon

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer. Actually, spring does use a bound scope in the essence that my client apps are given a scope upon registration and if the scope they request is different than what they are allowed (they can request any subset of what they're allowed) then an error is thrown. What I don't understand is why not allow no scope to be requested and then have the default agreed, upon registration, scope be returned.

Comment: This is actually the same process that PayPal Access uses - you define what you want within the application and then again when you make the request.  There isn't actually a reason to do it this way and it was probably just implemented for additional verification.  I'd like to tell you that there is a reason in the spec for doing this, but there really isn't - it's just how they chose to do it.  If it helps, I agree with you 100% on the defaults.  This is a model that Facebook uses and I like it quite a bit.